any difference in network interaction between creating and reusing clients each grpc call?
I know channel should be reused.
but any differece in nerwork round trip  between creating and reusing clients each grpc call ?
Code 1:

  GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://127.0.0.1:22137");

           for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           {
               CmdService.CmdServiceClient rpcClient = new CmdService.CmdServiceClient(channel);

               CmdResponse resp = rpcClient.RunCommand(new CmdRequest(), deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10));

           }

           channel.Dispose();


Code 2:

GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://127.0.0.1:22137");

CmdService.CmdServiceClient rpcClient = new CmdService.CmdServiceClient(channel);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    CmdResponse resp = rpcClient.RunCommand(new CmdRequest(), deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10));

}

channel.Dispose();


code2 and code1 has any differece in nerwork round trip  ?
